# React Navigation : native Stack Navigator / native-stack is much slower on Android since React Native 0.68.1

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Since I updated to Expo 45 and RN 0.68, @react-navigation/native-stack StackActions.push() animation is very smooth but much slower on Android (I didn't notice that on IOS), is it a part of the upgrade ? Is there a way to make it fast as before ?